# Unable to get relative paths working in... Smarty :(

Tags: php, smarty

I'm stuck on using Smarty (3.1.16 I think) for a university project.
I have this directory structure:

```
+ templates/
+ -- application.tpl
+ -- backend.tpl
+ -- backend/
+ ---- blog.tpl
```

Inside `templates/backend.tpl` I have an `{extends 'application.tpl'}` which works when I load `backend.php` and render this file.

Inside `templates/backend/blog.tpl` I have an `{extends '../backend.tpl'}`. When I visit `backend/blog.php` (which loads `templates/backend/blog.tpl`) I get this error:

```
Unable to read template file 'application.tpl'
```

What could be the reason of this error?

Comment: Isn't your `application.tpl` one folder back to where your `backend.tpl` is?

Comment: @OhhMee Sorry, typo! I updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the path you set at this point is relative to the set template directory, not to the file itself.

So `../backend.tpl` becomes `templates/../backend.tpl`

In case you have set a single template folder ("templates"), it should work when replace

```
{extends '../backend.tpl'}
```

with

```
{extends 'backend.tpl'}
```

You can also define multiple template directories and indentify them by an array index (optional).
Use the [setTemplateDir](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.set.template.dir.tpl) method to setup smarty for this behavior

```
$smarty->setTemplateDir(array(
   'frontend' => 'templates',
   'backend' => 'templates/backend'
));
```

In your templates you can now include/extend templates from a specific directory with the smarty file protokol like so

```
{extends 'file:[backend]blog.tpl'}
```

Comment: Actually, it loads `backend.tpl` when I write `{extends '../backend.tpl}` (which it doesn't when I don't write the relative path), the problem is (as I wrote in the question) that it isn't able to load `application.tpl`.

Comment: Just a minor question: should I use an entire Smarty object for the whole application or should I create a `new Smarty()` for each PHP script?

Comment: This doesn't matter as long as you separate the basic configuration (cache,compiles,templates,...). You could extend the smarty class and constructor (append the configuration here) and instantiate this on each script. Depended on your application you can also init the object as a singleton but then you have to take care about double assigns or similar issues.

Comment: How does the display/fetch call looks like in your backend/blog.php ?